# 19.10 GRUB GUI Not Visible on Load

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, 19.10

I've just dual booted my UEFI Dell Inspiron 7537 Windows 10 system with Ubuntu 19.10. The installation went fine, but I'm having an issue with GRUB at boot time.

The GUI for GRUB does not appear at boot time. GRUB appears to be working in the background, as the boot pauses, and boots into whatever OS I set as the preferred option after the set timeout time (I've varied from 10-30 seconds), or I can use the arrow and enter keys to boot into my preferred OS, knowing where it is in the list.
However it's not visible and instead I am looking at a black screen with a white underscore cursor in the top right.

I have disabled secure boot and fast boot. I tried disabling Legacy Option ROM but that just made it harder to get into the F2 and F12 menus.

Ubuntu is chosen as the preferred bootloader in the BIOS/UEFI boot settings. If I go into the boot options and select Ubuntu it brings up the GUI, so it appears to be an issue with the GUI loading from a cold start/reboot scenario only.

The basic version of GRUB works if I uncomment "GRUB_TERMINAL=console" but I want to get the GUI working, as I dislike the console look.

Does anyone know how I might fix this? I've read a lot of other similar questions, but, while similar, they don't seem to be the same issue.